# How to put images to ImageView with glide

Tags: java, android

i have some view on my screen that contains 3 `ImageView`.
I have another view (RecyclerView) that contain 30 icons.
I want that when I'm clicking on some icon from RV, it will be added to the container with 3 `ImageView` to the first `ImageView`.
If i click again on some other icon from RV, and `ImageView` at `index 0` is already used by previous clicked icon, this icon will be moved to index 1 and the new one will be added to the index 0.

There is a code I have now:
For now , it always add the icon the the `index 0` .

XML":

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/historyContainer1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/historyContainer2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/historyContainer3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Fragment that contain the images:

```
private ArrayList<ImageView> historyItemsPH = new ArrayList<>();


historyItemsPH.add(mHistoryContainer1);
historyItemsPH.add(mHistoryContainer2);
historyItemsPH.add(mHistoryContainer3);

mLightsAdapter.setOnLightImageTouchListener(new LightsAdapter.OnLightImageTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLightImageTouch(final int position, MotionEvent event, LightsAdapter.LightsViewHolder holder) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
                    mainActivity.removeSortFragment();
                }
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    mEmptyHistoryTXT.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    Glide.with(getContext())
                            .load(mLightsArray.get(position).getLampImageUrl())
                            .override(150)
                            .into(historyItemsPH.get(0));
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This will add to next every time, to do like you want you have to add more logic)

```
int i = 0;
private ArrayList<ImageView> historyItemsPH = new ArrayList<>();


historyItemsPH.add(mHistoryContainer1);
historyItemsPH.add(mHistoryContainer2);
historyItemsPH.add(mHistoryContainer3);

mLightsAdapter.setOnLightImageTouchListener(new LightsAdapter.OnLightImageTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLightImageTouch(final int position, MotionEvent event, LightsAdapter.LightsViewHolder holder) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
                    mainActivity.removeSortFragment();
                }
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    mEmptyHistoryTXT.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    Glide.with(getContext())
                            .load(mLightsArray.get(position).getLampImageUrl())
                            .override(150)
                            .into(historyItemsPH.get(i));
                    i++;
                    if (i==3){
                       i = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```